# Hover on images are not shown after migration on Wordpress Site

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I recently moved site from one domain to another, and updated permalinks to fit to [new domain](http://www.zineki.com). But noticed that, image element on homepage (bellow slider) dont gray when you close to it, like on [previous domain](http://spas-hammam.com/ZineChic/). Im talking about this element:

[image: image from issue part]

and this is CSS that is generating that hover effect:

```
.quickfinder-item-effect-image-scale .quickfinder-item-picture:after {
  background: transparent;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}

.quickfinder-item-effect-image-scale.hover .quickfinder-item-picture:after {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
```

Im not sure why is not working, when i make a complete backup and files backup , and transfered to a new domain. Seems like JS issue, but dont know why. What i do. Any tip how to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no anchor tag `<a>` for the category items in new domain:

Old site HTML:

[image]

New site html:

[image]

You can see that the `<a>` tag is missing from the new site. It's probably a theme setting somewhere that has been set back to default.

Comment: Yes indead was element feature removed aftere migrating.Thanks. resolved.